# What is wrong in my Math max functions?

Tags: javascript

```
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    var numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6, 7];
        var i,
            len = numberArray.length,
            imGreater = numberArray[0];
     for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       maxNumber = Math.max(len)   
    }       
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  console.log(maxNumber );
    }
  </script>
```

What is wrong with it? Is it about Javascript scope?

Comment: you are using 'max' on the length of the array, which doesn't actually change. Your function is doing the right thing, but I'm assuming you are using it wrongly ;-)

Comment: `maxNumber = Math.max.apply(null, numberArray)`

Comment: All you really need is `maxNumber = Math.max.apply(Math, numberArray)`

Comment: Thanks. but what means "Math" in nails? Cannot i just use Math.max.apply(numberArray) ?

Comment: Is the object you can use as "this" reference in your function implementation

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is 'wrong' with it, in the sense that it is doing exactly what you are asking. You are running `Math.max`on the length of the array, which does not change and is probably not what you are trying to do. I think you want to run it against the actual array 
`Math.max.apply(null,numberArray);` 
As this will give you the highest number in the provided array.

---

### Doing it yourself

You could write this yourself in the loop as well, which might be what you are trying to do as well, considering you created a loop and set up some variables. Starting after the creation of these variables you could write the following loop

```
for(i = 1; i < len; i++) // you can skip the first one as this is set to imGreater already
{
 if(numberArray[i] > imGreater)
 {
    imGreater = numberArray[i];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## use :

```
  Math.max(...numberArray);
```

instead of

```
   Math.max(len)
```

---

## use

```
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  maxNumber ;
```

Instead of :

```
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  console.log(maxNumber) ;
```

---

DEMO  :

```js
var numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6, 7];
var maxVal=Math.max(...numberArray);
console.log(maxVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example on fiddle, just use Math.max (already predefined in JS).

```js
var numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6, 7];
alert(Math.max.apply(Math,numberArray));
```

Here is another working example `(Your style)`:

```js
 var numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6, 7];
    var maxNumber = 0;
    var len = numberArray.length;
    for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
      if(numberArray[i] > maxNumber){
        maxNumber=numberArray[i];
      }
    }       
    alert(maxNumber);
```